# How to use RabbitTemplate in all Java classes

Tags: java, spring, spring-amqp

I edited my code into this configuration:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class EndPoint {


String QUEUE_PROCESSING_TRANSACTION = "processing-process-queue";
String QUEUE_DATABASE_TRANSACTION = "database-transa-queue";
......

@Bean
public Queue queueProcessingTransaction() {
    return new Queue(QUEUE_PROCESSING_TRANSACTION, true);
}

@Bean
public Queue queueDatabaseEventLogs() {
    return new Queue(QUEUE_DATABASE_EVENT_LOGS, true);
}

@Bean
public Binding bindingQueueProcessingTransaction() {
   return BindingBuilder.bind(new Queu........
}

@Bean
public CachingConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
    CachingConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new CachingConnectionFactory(HOST);
    return connectionFactory;
}

@Bean
public AmqpAdmin amqpAdmin(CachingConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
RabbitAdmin admin = new RabbitAdmin(connectionFactory);
.........
admin.declareQueue(new Queue(QUEUE_PROCESSING_TRANSACTION, true));
return admin;
}

@Bean
public RabbitTemplate processingTemplate(CachingConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
RabbitTemplate processingTemplate = new RabbitTemplate(connectionFactory);
processingTemplate.setExchange(EXCHANGE_PROCESSING);
.......
return processingTemplate;
}
```

Previously I used this configuration into Java class which I extend in second Java class in order to access RabbitTemplate.
How I can use RabbitTemplate in Java classes? Probably there is already implemented facility designed in Spring?

Comment: Use something like `@Autowired RabbitTemplate template` to Inject a RabbitTemplate in the Spring bean in which you need it.

Comment: Thanks, can you show me example how I can inject it in some location?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just add another bean that creates a template starting from the connection factory:

```
@Bean
public RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate(CachingConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
   RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate = new RabbitTemplate(connectionFactory);
   return rabbitTemplate;
}
```

You can autowire it in container managed classes:

```
@Autowired private RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate;
```

Comment: Ok, but how I can call it into another Java Class?

Comment: Simply by autowire, as added in the post.

Comment: I need to add @Autowired private RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate; into the source or into the destination Class?

Comment: @PeterPenzov Destination, where you want to use it. The source is the definition with `@Bean`.

Answer (score 2):

You can inject the RabbitTemplate bean in another Spring Bean and use it, so for example you can create a new Spring Bean (component) like the following:

```
@Component
public class MyComponent {

  @Autowired
  private RabbitTemplate template;

  public void testRabbitTemplate() {
    System.out.println(template);
  }
}
```

Remember that the injection works only if you retrieve `MyComponent` from the Spring Context (i.e. you must not instantiate it using the `new` keyword).

You can also inject the same RabbitTemplate in your `EndPoint` class simply adding the following line into the class body:

```
@Autowired private RabbitTemplate template;
```